# Anime with a scene where two male prisoners fight while being transported

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw this clip of an anime on TikTok the other day and it was a scene where there were two male prisoners being transported and during the trip they're about to fight and one says “I don’t want to fight because my wife hates it when I do” and then wins the fight of course. It looked like it was set in like ancient times cuz there were samurai swords and everything & I think the guy that won was blonde? And his handler was a woman?

This is probably not very specific but it's been in the back of my mind and I haven't been able to come across the TikTok again. Thank you!

Comment: You appear to have asked this elsewhere and already received an answer;  https://twitter.com/NotTramBraxton/status/1651661565114851343

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about that specific fight, but this sounds like [Jigokuraku / Hell's Paradise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell%27s_Paradise:_Jigokuraku), a currently airing show about a superhuman/immortal guy, motivated by love for his wife, in a Shogunate-era "Suicide Squad" style arrangement with a female samurai handler who has to fight other condemned criminals.

[This clip](https://youtu.be/4hgIRvPx8cw) takes place on a beach rather than a boat, but should let you recognize the characters if I'm right.